# How to build a protractor without a protractor?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

We all know how to use a protractor, it is taught in elementary school. However, I was wondering what type of knowledge is required to build one from scratch.

For instance, was the understanding of $\pi$ and a compass first required before the first protractor, and if so how can I draw a full protractor on paper with just a compass, a ruler and some understanding of $\pi$?

I guess my point is as follows. If we can draw a semi-circle on paper, then how can we fill up the degrees without the help of a protractor?

Comment: This is not a history question, you should ask on Math SE or MathEd SE. Bisecting the semicircle iteratively will give you the basic markup, the rest can be interpolated. [Ptolemy's table of chords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_table_of_chords) construction gives an idea how.

Answer (score 5):

Until the middle of 18th century, division of the circle (when high precision was required) was performed by compass,
by starting with a regular pentagon or hexagon, and then performing bisections, additions and subtractions of arcs. This was a normal procedure of manufacturing astronomical instruments. Only in 18th century a division engine was invented, which [performed the task mechanically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dividing_engine).

For example, in the middle of 18 century they were able to divide an arc of radius 2-12 inches into minutes, so that the overall error in measuring any was less than 1 minute. By hands, and using only compass.

One cannot divide a circle into 360 equal parts exactly, using a compass only, so 1 degree angle could be obtained only approximately. But with any requires accuracy.

This fact was known experimentally, and proved only in 19th century: using a compass, you can divide the circle into $n$ equal parts, if and only if $n=2^kp_1p_2,...$, where $p_k$ are distinct primes of the form $2^{2^m}+1$. Since $360=2^3.3.3.5$, one cannot divide the circle into 360 parts  exactly.

One does not need "the knowledge of $\pi$" (whatever this can mean) for this procedure. Everything is based on simple geometry, and the use of compass. Division of a straight ruler into equal parts by a compass is possible for any number of parts. But from the practical point of view, it is of the same difficulty as for a circle.

Comment: Are you implying that 360 degrees on circle are not identically spaced?

Comment: @AChem I think the implication is that the 360 degrees on the measuring instrument were not identically spaced. This is sort of true of all measuring instruments - there is no such thing as perfect precision. Adam Savage has a very interesting video on this idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qE7dYhpI_bI&t=1s

Comment: @Wossname I am a little surprised! Suppose we have the ability to make a perfect measuring device, yet we cannot make an equally spaced 360 degrees on a circle?

Comment: I think Eremenko means the 360 division on the circumference via compass is not possible.

Comment: I said that using a compass, it is not possible to divide a circle into 360 parts exactly, but possible to divide with ANY GIVEN accuracy, so they are as good as desired for all practical purposes. And that until 18 century they did build them with this method.